# Linking a Qst to the first Qst asked for the user in Python

Tags: python

I came here one more time to ask yet another question. This is for the same code I am working on. I have written the code below. But my question is **that how can you link my last question, for example the user answered no instead of yes, how can I make it link back to the first question which is Did you drop your phone?**

Thanks in advance!

**CODE:**

```
if input("Did you  buy your phone recently? ") == 'yes':
if input("Did you drop your phone? ") == 'yes':
    if input("Did it become wet when you dropped it? ") == 'yes':
     print(sol1)
else:  
    if input("Is the phone fully charged? ") == 'yes':
        print("")
    else:  
        print(sol2) 
else:  
if input("Has your phone ever been too slow? " ) == 'yes':
    print(solution)
else:  
    if input("Have you got more than 30 apps? ") == 'yes':
        print(sol0)
```

Comment: You could write a function for the questions and call the function itself based on the answer. Additionally you should think about having a kind of flowchart in your mind telling you where to go from which question. In my opinion developing a UI based on something like a flowchart is easier instead of adding more and more branches later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first include all your code in a [function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm), which will allow you to reuse code without retyping everything.

Then, when you get to the point where you want to go back to the first question, just call this function. I would also advise you to add a return statement after you print the solution, otherwise you will never exit your function.

Here is a (simplified) example:

```
def phone():
    if input("Did you  buy your phone recently? ") == 'yes':
        if input("Did you drop your phone? ") == 'yes':
            print sol1
            return
        else: 
            print sol2 
            return

    else:
        phone() #this will make you go back to the start of your function, in this case the first question
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me alot!